# Error message "Invalid option -session"

Tags: debian, xorg, xfce

When I start Xorg on my Debian8 (Jessie), and when session is ready to work I get error message "invalid option -session". When I skip this message there's nothing wrong happens. I use Xfce graphical environment, when tried run FluxBox(I know it's only window manager) don't get error box. 
What can I do to prevent our message?

Answer (score 3):

Let me guess, you have Spotify installed and you're automatically saving your session ;)

Spotify is restarted by a command containing

> " -session"

which obviously xfce has issues with. I can't tell you exactly why, I just know that by closing spotify before restarting, it's not put into the session files at `.cache/sessions` and therefore not loaded upon next login.

Hope this helps